# Is it possible to set excluded folders for IDEA from SBT?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I have a large multi module SBT project. One module is a Play2 project. Now, by default, IntelliJ IDEA excludes the whole `target` folder and IDEA's own compiler does not run the `compile` goal from sbt, but tries to figure everything out itself. This leads to important Play2 parts like routes and reverse routers not built.

When I run `sbt compile` from the console, these components are built, but since they are in the `target` folder which is excluded in IDEA by default, IDEA ignores everything in there.

Every time when switching Git branches (the Play2 project is only in one branch as of now) I have to go into the project structure and adjust the excluded folders manually.

Is it somehow possible to have IDEA figure this out by itself, and call `sbt compile` when rebuilding the project?